# Mongo C# Aggregate convert ObjectId to string in Lookup foreignField

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection, call it Collection 1, that contains an array of Id values in string form. The values reference the documents of a User collection:

Collection 1

```
document 1
users array:
users[0]: "abc..."
users[1]: "mno..."
users[2]: "xyz..."
```

User Collection

```
document 1
_id: "abc..."
field1
field2

document 2
_id: "mno..."
field1
field2

document 3
_id: "xyz..."
field1
field2
```

The database is hosted in Atlas. I'm using the Mongo C# driver (MongoDB.Driver v2.11.5) to perform an aggregation lookup to join Collection 1 to the Users collection. The problem is, Collection 1 has the _id values as strings while User, of course, contains ObjectId values. I have been unable to figure out how to tell the C# Mongo driver to either convert the Collection 1 string to an ObjectId, or conversely, convert User._id to a string. Without this, the join will fail.

This is the sort of thing I've been trying, without success, for the foreignField argument:

```
var result = collection1.Aggregate()
      .Lookup("user", "users", "{{$toString: $_id}}" , "userDocs")  // nope
      .ToList();
```

Maybe I can't do it with the C# fluent approach and have to switch to BSON documents?  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: as one of the first steps in your aggregation, change the type of the source records key field so it matches the type of the lookup collection field.   See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/

Comment: @barrypicker  that sounds promising. I'll check it out. Thank you.